# Capturing verbose output from -Verbose switch in PowerShell v2

Tags: powershell, output, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I ran into an interesting issue today that has me puzzled. I need to capture output from the verbose stream and write it to stdout.

This can be accomplished with this:

```
# Create a PowerShell Command 

$pscmd = [PowerShell]::Create() 

# Add a Script to change the verbose preference. 
# Since I want to make sure this change stays around after I run the command I set UseLocalScope to $false. 
# Also note that since AddScript returns the PowerShell command, I can simply call Invoke on what came back. 
# I set the return value to $null to suppress any output 

$null = $psCmd.AddScript({$VerbosePreference = "Continue"},$false).Invoke() 

# If I added more commands, I'd be adding them to the pipeline, so I want to clear the pipeline 

$psCmd.Commands.Clear() 

# Now that I've cleared the pipeline, I'll add another script that writes out 100 messages to the Verbose stream 

$null = $psCmd.AddScript({Write-verbose "hello World" }).Invoke() 

# Finally, I'll output the stream 

$psCmd.Streams.Verbose
```

Now the interesting part is if I were to create a function called `Hello-World` and use `[CmdletBinding()]` to inherit the -verbose switch, I can no longer capture output:

```
Function Hello-World {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Verbose "hello world"
}

...
$null = $psCmd.AddScript({Hello-World -Verbose }).Invoke() 
...
```

I am assuming that the function is given its own verbose stream and that visibility to the stream is lost, but I am not positive. Does this have to do with `[CmdletBinding()]`?

Avoiding transcripts, is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the function is executing properly?  It may be that the function isn't defined in the new powershell instance you're dealing with.

Comment: Also, within an advanced function ([CmdletBinding()]) you should be using `$pscmdlet.WriteVerbose("Hello World")`

Comment: Ahh, that was it, I'll post an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @JasonMorgan, below is the solution that appears to be working. I needed to declare the function in the pscmd I made:

```
$pscmd = [PowerShell]::Create() 

$null = $psCmd.AddScript({$VerbosePreference = "Continue"},$false).Invoke()
$null = $psCmd.AddScript({
  function Hello-World {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Write-Verbose "hello world"
  }
}, $false).Invoke() 

$psCmd.Commands.Clear() 

$null = $psCmd.AddScript({Hello-World -Verbose }).Invoke() 

$psCmd.Streams.Verbose
```